# 【iOS】error in targetcontentoffset, which is inconsistent with the real stop position

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using textview, which has very large text. I need to get the exact location of the final stop before the user stops scrolling
I use the following code. When the user's sliding distance is very small, it can work (but there is also a small error). When the user's sliding distance is very large, such as sliding for 10 times continuously, its expected position is inaccurate

```
- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset{
     CGPoint willEndPoint = *targetContentOffset;
     //Where it is expected to stop
     NSLog(@"expected to stop：%f",willEndPoint.y);
}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScroll {
    NSLog(@"Actual stop position：%f",self.textView.contentOffset.y);
}
```

targetcontentoffset and self textView. contentOffset. There is an error between y. when the sliding distance is very small, their error is very small, between 1 and 5, but when my text has tens of thousands of lines, and users slide down madly, their gap will be very large. I have a need to get the exact final stop position before the scrolling stops. Obviously, the error of getting targetcontentoffset makes me unable to do this. I'm very confused. I guess it's because textview doesn't load all the content at once. In the process of scrolling, it loads new content, which leads to this error, so, Is there any way for me to get the exact final stop position before rolling stops

The following is a complete demo

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController ()<UITextViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITextView *textView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.textView = [[UITextView alloc]init];
    self.textView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    [self.view addSubview:self.textView];
    self.textView.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:50];
    NSString *str = @"";
    for(int i = 1; i < 10000;i++){
        str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%i\n",str,1];
    }
    self.textView.text = str;
    self.textView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset{
     CGPoint willEndPoint = *targetContentOffset;
     //Where it is expected to stop
     NSLog(@"expected to stop：%f",willEndPoint.y);
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    BOOL scrollToScrollStop = !scrollView.tracking && !scrollView.dragging && !scrollView.decelerating;
    if (scrollToScrollStop) {
        [self scrollViewDidEndScroll];
    }
}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
    if (!decelerate) {
        BOOL dragToDragStop = scrollView.tracking && !scrollView.dragging && !scrollView.decelerating;
        if (dragToDragStop) {
            [self scrollViewDidEndScroll];
        }
    }
}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndScroll {
    NSLog(@"Actual stop position：%f",self.textView.contentOffset.y);
}
```

When the user slides continuously for 2-3 times：
[image]

When the user slides continuously for more than 10 times
[image]

Comment: No one? Is this an unsolvable problem

Answer (score 0):

I think the second method you are using is the wrong one. That will be called when the user ends scrolling. But not when the scroll view stops updating.

If there is a velocity when the user ends scrolling then you will want to use the method `didEndDecelerating` instead…

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollviewdelegate/1619417-scrollviewdidenddecelerating

Comment: Sorry, I didn't describe it clearly. I have modified my problem. Please have a look again